# Type error: Property 'Store' is missing in type '{}' but required in type 'Readonly<Istore>'. TS2741

Tags: reactjs, typescript, mobx

Hi can you please help me fix this.

All I'm trying todo to pass my store in as props to the component, but I get this error

```
Type error: Property 'Store' is missing in type '{}' but required in type 'Readonly<Istore>'.  TS2741
```

```js
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import { observable, computed } from 'mobx'
import { observer } from 'mobx-react'
import TodoListView from "./TodoListView";
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'
import NotesAdd from './NotesAdd';
import NotesView from './NotesView';
import DevTools from 'mobx-react-devtools'
import Loader from './Loader';
import { Store } from "../store/Store"
import makeInspectable from 'mobx-devtools-mst';
import Wall from './Wall';
import { inject } from 'mobx-react';
import NotesStore from "../store/NotesStore";
import CounterStore from "../store/CounterStore";


interface IStoreStores {
    NotesStore: NotesStore,
    CounterStore: CounterStore,
}

interface Istore {
    Store: IStoreStores
}


@inject("Store")
@observer
class Box extends Component<Istore> {
    render() {
        console.log('props', this.props)
        return (
            <div className="Box p-3" >
                box component {this.props.Store.CounterStore.counter}
        <Wall />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Box;
```

Comment: I think you should make Store prop optional. interface Istore {
    Store?: IStoreStores
}

Answer (score -1):

Store prop is mandatory in this:

```
interface Istore {
    Store: IStoreStores
}
```

change it to optional:

```
interface Istore {
    Store?: IStoreStores
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Create a static defaultProps property in your class.

```
static defaultProps = { 
     NotesStore: NotesStore,
    CounterStore: CounterStore
};
```